# Combine 2 SELECTS in one result Side By Side

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mysql5

I have 2 selects that just get the SUM of IDs and are grouped by month.. I would like to have them only on 1 SELECT - side by side...

```
SELECT MONTH(data) AS month, COUNT(id) AS TOTAL
FROM numeracao
WHERE data BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-12-31'
GROUP BY MONTH(DATA);
```

the 2nd select:

```
SELECT MONTH(dia) AS month, COUNT(id) AS TOTAL
FROM revisoes
WHERE dia BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-12-31'
GROUP BY MONTH(dia)
```

The rewsult was to be expected somethinig like this:

| month | NUM | REV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | 4 |
| 2 | 52 | 23 |
| ... | ... | ... |

where:

- month is from 1 to 12
- NUM is the sum of query 1 on table numeracao
- REV is the sum of query 2 on table revisoes

Comment: Yes.. I did with UNION, but they are not summed by month.
For January I get 2 lines/results

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the inner join on the results of the aggregations to make counts appear on the same row for each month.

```
SELECT numtab.month, 
       numtab.num, 
       revtab.rev
FROM       (SELECT MONTH(data) AS month, COUNT(id) AS num
            FROM numeracao
            WHERE data BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-12-31'
            GROUP BY MONTH(DATA))                         numtab 
INNER JOIN (SELECT MONTH(dia) AS month, COUNT(id) AS rev
            FROM revisoes
            WHERE dia BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-12-31'
            GROUP BY MONTH(dia))                          revtab
        ON numtab.month = revtab.month
```

Computing the aggregation after the inner join would bring to duplicate rows and incorrect output, given than the two tables most likely have a n-to-n association.

---

If you're not ensured to have at least one value for all months on both tables, you should have a month calendar table and use left join instead.

```
SELECT calendar.month, 
       numtab.num, 
       revtab.rev
FROM      (SELECT 1 AS month UNION ALL
           SELECT 2 AS month UNION ALL
           SELECT 3 AS month UNION ALL
           SELECT 4 AS month UNION ALL
           SELECT 5 AS month UNION ALL
           SELECT 6 AS month UNION ALL
           SELECT 7 AS month UNION ALL
           SELECT 8 AS month UNION ALL
           SELECT 9 AS month UNION ALL
           SELECT 10 AS month UNION ALL
           SELECT 11 AS month UNION ALL
           SELECT 12 AS month           ) calendar
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MONTH(data) AS month, COUNT(id) AS num
           FROM numeracao
           WHERE data BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-12-31'
           GROUP BY MONTH(DATA)) numtab 
       ON calendar.month = numtab.month
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MONTH(dia) AS month, COUNT(id) AS rev
           FROM revisoes
           WHERE dia BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-12-31'
           GROUP BY MONTH(dia)) revtab
        ON calendar.month = revtab.month
```

I wouldn't recommend this one anyways if your problem gets solved with the former query.

Comment: I'm not an expert... It gives Syntax error on line 1

Comment: You are most likely using a legacy version of MySQL DBMS, where ctes are not allowed.

Comment: Just to note this won't work if either query has no rows for any month

Comment: Nice catch, I'll update the query accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using *union* and then an outer aggregation:

```
select Month, Max(Num) Num, Max(Rev) Rev
from (
  select Month(data) as month, Count(id) Num, null Rev
  from numeracao
  where data between '2023-01-01' and '2023-12-31'
  group by Month(DATA)
  union all
  select Month(dia) as month, null Num, Count(id) Rev
  from revisoes
  where dia between '2023-01-01' and '2023-12-31'
  group by Month(dia)
)t;
```

Comment: Gosh... Yes.. it works... Yep!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT month,TOTAL FROM(SELECT MONTH(data) AS month, COUNT(id) AS TOTAL
FROM numeracao
WHERE data BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-12-31'
GROUP BY MONTH(DATA)
UNION ALL
SELECT MONTH(dia) AS month, COUNT(id) AS TOTAL
FROM revisoes
WHERE dia BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-12-31' )as rows
GROUP BY month
```

Comment: I'm not an expert as I said to @lemon ... This one gives:
"every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: I have updated the query please look into it